# JAVA: Cast String to (dynamically known) primitive type in order to instantiate a (dynamically known) class

Tags: java, reflection

I have a repository class that uses **text files**(*a requirement*), meaning that I have to read strings and cast them in order to instantiate objects. The problem is that I want my repository class as general as I can make it, in order to use it to manipulate different object types.

So, is there a (more elegant) way to dynamically cast strings to whatever field (primitive) type it needs at runtime, while avoiding lots of 
try-catch structures with numerous ifs/switches?

As a short simplified version, I want *objectA.txt* to contain only objectA's information, similarly for *objectB.txt*, and my Repository code to handle both:

Repository repo**A** = new Repository("objectA.txt", < *list of Types for A* >); Type**A** a=repoA.getOne();

Repository repo**B** = new Repository("objectB.txt", < *list of Types for B* >); Type**B** b=repoB.getOne();

What I have:

```
public class FileRepository extends InMemoryRepository{
    private String fileName;
    private List<Class> types;

    public FileRepository(String fileName, List<Class> types) {
        //@param types 
        //     - list containing the Class to be instantiated followed by it's field types
        super();
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.types=types;
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);

        try {
            Files.lines(path).forEach(line -> {
                List<String> items = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));

                //create Class array for calling the correct constructor
                Class[] cls=new Class[types.size()-1];
                for (int i=1; i<types.size(); i++){
                    cls[i-1]=types.get(i);
                }

                Constructor constr=null;
                try {
                    //get the needed constructor
                    constr = types.get(0).getConstructor(cls);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    //do something
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //here is where the fun begins
                //@arg0 ... @argn are the primitives that need to be casted from string 
                //something like: 
                //*(type.get(1))* arg0=*(cast to types.get(1))* items.get(0);
                //*(type.get(2))* arg1=*(cast to types.get(2))* items.get(1);
                //...

                Object obj= (Object) constr.newInstance(@arg0 ... @argn);

            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

P.S.: I'm a JAVA newbie, so please keep the explanations as simple as possible.

Comment: couldn't you serialize each item with a code in the beginning that would tell the repository implementation which type it contains?

Comment: what class will be in List in case of primitive type int?

Comment: @Lashane int.class

Comment: @MarianP not sure how that would help my string conversion. please elaborate

Comment: @mrb33st right, what object will be returned by `int.class.newInstance()`?

Comment: It would be rather simple if that "text" could be an XML text. Code out of the box can handle all simple types, at least. (Or JSON, anybody?)

Comment: @Lashane I know I can't instantiate int or other primitives like this, ergo my question

Comment: @laune yeah, XML would be nice, but I have to use plain txt

Comment: You can't instantiate primitives, but you can instantiate primitive wrappers, for example [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Comment: Would you consider wrapping your "have-to-text" chunks into XML on the fly? You do know the field names for the @args, so it's fairly straightforward.

Comment: Identifying the components of an object by their types, with the intent of selecting a constructor by a certain combination of said types, is a rather shaky way of creating objects from data. Just consider the ubiquitous triangle: three sides, two sides and one angle, one side and two angles,...: all is three doubles.

Comment: @laune I have considered it and will implement it as a last resort. I wanted to know if there are other ways - other Java specific ways that I know nothing of. I searched everywhere today about this and found nothing but tangential information that does not help very much.

Comment: What do you expect? You have data in some non-standardized format - so from where should that magic wand come and convert characters to Java values of various types? String alone reqires a lexer, if done right.

Comment: This is not casting. It is conversion.

Answer (score 2):

No IDE on hand, so I hope this makes sense:

```
private static final Map<Class, Function<String, ?>> parsers = new HashMap<>();

static {
  parsers.put(Long.class, Long::parseLong);
  parsers.put(Integer.class, Integer::parseInt);
  parsers.put(String.class, String::toString);
  parsers.put(Double.class, Double::parseDouble);
  parsers.put(Float.class, Float::parseFloat);
  // add your own types here.
}

public <T> T parse(Class<T> klass, String value) {
  // add some null-handling logic here? and empty values.
  return (T)parsers.get(klass).apply(value);
}
```

Then when you need to create the parameters for your constructor:

```
parameters =
     IntStream
     .range(0, cls.size-1)
     .map(i -> (Object)parse(types.get(i), items.get(i)))
     .toArray(Object[]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of auto-boxing and auto-unboxing coupled with the observation that all wrapper classes provide a method named `valueOf` that accepts a **String** and returns an instance of the respective (wrapper) type such that the given string represents the legal *value* of that type.

The following is an attempt of a type-safe implementation that suits your needs:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

/**
 * Created by kmhaswade on 3/18/16.
 */
//@ThreadUnsafe
public class NonStreamingGenericPrimitiveDataRepo<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<T>() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return theIterator.hasNext();
            }

            @Override
            public T next() {
                String next = theIterator.next();
                try {
                    Method m = theType.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class);
                    return (T) m.invoke(null, next);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("This is impossible!");
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("data: " + next + " does not represent type: " + theType);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        throw new RuntimeException("left as an exercise :-) ");
    }
    private final ArrayList<String> theCache;
    private final Iterator<String> theIterator;
    private final Class<T> theType;
    public NonStreamingGenericPrimitiveDataRepo(Reader reader, Class<T> theType) throws IOException {
        Objects.requireNonNull(reader);
        Objects.requireNonNull(theType);
        if (Integer.class.equals(theType)
                || Long.class.equals(theType)
                || Float.class.equals(theType)
                || Double.class.equals(theType)
                || Boolean.class.equals(theType)
                || String.class.equals(theType)) {
            theCache = new ArrayList<>();
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    theCache.add(line);
            }
            theIterator = theCache.iterator();
            this.theType = theType;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a wrapper type: " + theType);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i : new NonStreamingGenericPrimitiveDataRepo<>(ints(), Integer.class))
            System.out.println("read an int: " + i);
        for (float f : new NonStreamingGenericPrimitiveDataRepo<>(floats(), Float.class))
            System.out.println("read a float: " + f);
        for (boolean b: new NonStreamingGenericPrimitiveDataRepo<>(booleans(), Boolean.class))
            System.out.println("read a boolean: " + b);
    }
    static StringReader ints() {
        return new StringReader("1.w\n2\n-3\n4\n");
    }
    static StringReader floats() {
        return new StringReader("1.0f\n3.25f\n-3.33f\n4.44f\n");
    }
    static StringReader booleans() {
        return new StringReader("false \ntrue\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify the type of primitive data type from a String, you can use the following:

```
public class Test {

    final static String LONG_PATTERN = "[-+]?\\d+";
    final static String DOUBLE_PATTERN = "[-+]?(\\d*[.])?\\d+";
    final static String BOOLEAN_PATTERN = "(true|false)";
    final static String CHAR_PATTERN = "[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] xList= {
                "1", //int 
                "111111111111", //long 
                "1.1", //float
                "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.1", //double
                "c", //char
                "true", //boolean
                "end" //String
                };

        for (String x: xList){

            if(x.matches(LONG_PATTERN)){
                long temp = Long.parseLong(x);
                if (temp >= Integer.MIN_VALUE && temp <= Integer.MAX_VALUE){
                    System.out.println( x + " is int use downcast");
                } else {
                    System.out.println( x + " is long");
                }
            } else if(x.matches(DOUBLE_PATTERN)){
                double temp = Double.parseDouble(x);
                if (temp >= Float.MIN_VALUE && temp <= Float.MAX_VALUE){
                    System.out.println( x + " is float use downcast");
                } else {
                    System.out.println( x + " is Double");
                }
            } else if (x.toLowerCase().matches(BOOLEAN_PATTERN)){
                boolean temp = x.toLowerCase().equals("true");
                System.out.println(x + " is Boolean");
            } else if(x.length() == 1){
                System.out.println(x + " is char");
            }else {
                System.out.println( x + " is String");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 is int use downcast
111111111111 is long
1.1 is float use downcast
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.1 is Double
c is char
true is Boolean
end is String
```

The above code categorizes your String in 4 major parts long integer, double, boolean and if none matches then String. As java states, primitive data types fall in two categories:

```
Integers
    byte
    char (represented as a character)
    short
    int
    long
Floating point numbers
    float
    double
Boolean
    boolean
```

This way you will be able to identify the types in which your String lies. You can modify the code to check the range and type cast the numbers accordingly in byte and short as well.